# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS randomly freezes

Tags: 18.04, crash

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my computer alongside Windows 10. The problem is that while I am surfing the web or doing something else, the system freezes and I have to force shutdown and reboot. This happens randomly, usually takes about half an hour.

My hardware specifications are the following:
-Intel Core i3-3240
-nVidia GeForce GTX 660
I don't remember the motherboard or RAM models, but if they are useful I can try to search for them. I have 8 GB of RAM.

This is the logs file from the last crash:

```
16:21:29 kernel: sysrq: SysRq : Emergency Remount R/O
16:21:17 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: systemd-logind[745]: channel 12 killed!
16:20:36 nautilus: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
16:20:34 systemd: Started Hostname Service.
16:20:34 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
16:20:34 systemd: Starting Hostname Service...
16:20:34 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.133' (uid=1000 pid=4407 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
16:20:30 nautilus: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
16:20:00 systemd: Started Hostname Service.
16:20:00 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
16:20:00 systemd: Starting Hostname Service...
16:20:00 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.133' (uid=1000 pid=4407 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
16:19:44 nautilus: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
16:19:38 zeitgeist-daemo: [31m[15:19:38.843242 WARNING][0m zeitgeist-daemon.vala:127: Unable to parse version info!
16:19:38 systemd: Started Zeitgeist full-text search indexer.
16:19:38 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1369] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer'
16:19:38 systemd: Starting Zeitgeist full-text search indexer...
16:19:38 zeitgeist-daemo: [31m[15:19:38.689000 WARNING][0m zeitgeist-daemon.vala:334: Failed to execute child process “zeitgeist-datahub” (No such file or directory)
16:19:38 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1369] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine'
16:19:38 systemd: Starting Zeitgeist activity log service...
16:19:38 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1369] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine' unit='zeitgeist.service' requested by ':1.100' (uid=1000 pid=4407 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
16:18:46 systemd: Started Hostname Service.
16:18:46 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
16:18:46 systemd: Starting Hostname Service...
16:18:46 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.133' (uid=1000 pid=4407 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
16:17:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
16:16:31 systemd: Started Hostname Service.
16:16:31 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
16:16:31 nautilus: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
16:16:31 systemd: Starting Hostname Service...
16:16:31 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.133' (uid=1000 pid=4407 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
16:15:07 gnome-shell: (/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:4139): dconf-WARNING **: 16:15:07.532: Unable to open /var/lib/snapd/desktop/dconf/profile/user: Permission denied
16:14:53 systemd: Started Hostname Service.
16:14:53 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
16:14:53 nautilus: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
16:14:53 systemd: Starting Hostname Service...
16:14:52 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.131' (uid=1000 pid=4247 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
16:14:40 thunderbird: 1543936480446 addons.update-checker   WARN    Update manifest for messagingmenu@mozilla.com did not contain an updates property
16:10:36 gnome-shell: [Parent 1799, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (186): Connection reset by peer: file /build/firefox-JcIUVH/firefox-63.0.3+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 356
16:08:12 firefox: Attempting to read the recently used resources file at '/home/ivangouba/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed: Failed to open file “/home/ivangouba/.local/share/recently-used.xbel”: Permission denied.
16:08:01 wpa_supplicant: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-60 noise=-95 txrate=115600
16:04:13 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
16:02:45 gnome-shell: (/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:1992): dconf-WARNING **: 16:02:45.089: Unable to open /var/lib/snapd/desktop/dconf/profile/user: Permission denied
16:00:37 kernel: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
16:00:37 kernel: Anacron 2.3 started on 2018-12-04
16:00:37 systemd: Started Run anacron jobs.
15:53:46 gnome-shell: [Child 2392, MediaPlayback #3] WARNING: Decoder=7fb0007b8e20 Decode error: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) - RefPtr<mozilla::MozPromise<RefPtr<mozilla::MediaTrackDemuxer::SamplesHolder>, mozilla::MediaResult, true> > mozilla::MediaSourceTrackDemuxer::DoGetSamples(int32_t): manager is detached.: file /build/firefox-JcIUVH/firefox-63.0.3+build1/dom/media/MediaDecoderStateMachine.cpp, line 3429
15:52:12 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
15:50:49 systemd-resolve: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
15:50:35 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
15:49:27 whoopsie: [15:49:27] online
```

Thank you very much in advance. I will try to provide any needed extra information.

Comment: `16:21:29 kernel: sysrq: SysRq : Emergency Remount R/O` looks suspicious.

Comment: I think that is because I used the Alt+PrintScreen+REISUB command to reboot the computer.

Comment: I also have a similar issue. I was suspicious of google-chrome but disabled the GPU rendering on google-chrome and that did not help. I also ran a stress test on my CPU and memory. No problem with that either. I am a bit now suspicious about my drive which is an SSD NVMe but haven't found any clue. Btw, how did you obtain this log @ivangouba?

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the problem. Apparently, my graphics card (Nvidia GeForce GTX 660) doesn't work well with the default drivers, so I installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers and I haven't had a single crash since. To do it, I opened a terminal and I executed the following commands:

1. First, I added the Nvidia driver repository:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

2. Then, I updated the repositories and installed the driver:

> sudo apt update
>
> sudo apt install nvidia-387

The 387 after nvidia- is the version of the driver, which you should substitute with whatever version is the current at the moment when you install your drivers. If you don't know what version to use, I guess you can just use 387, which might be somewhat old, but it works.

I'm new to Ubuntu, so feel free to tell me if I have said something wrong.