# Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS freezes

Tags: 18.04, crash

I could not find an answer which help overcome this problem, so I decided to post new question. I have `16GB RAM` and `NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050]` and `AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor` on my machine. `Ubuntu` sometimes freezes - I can not move the mouse, the machine ignores whatever I press on my keyboard, I can not open another tty, I can only(?) use the power button. It happens approximately from 1 to 7 times per 8 hours of machine usage. I observed that it mostly happens when I use `Firefox` or `Skype`, but I really have doubts if it could be the rule. Generally, the machine should not be "bussy" too much, when it happens.

1. [This](https://medium.com/@gspasov2/how-to-fix-ubuntu-18-04-lts-random-freezes-52bb75d55c70) soultion, which suggests to run:

   ```
   sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
   ```

   gave no results
2. [That](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098493/ubuntu-18-04-lts-randomly-freezes) solution, which suggests to install Nvidia drivers:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   sudo apt install nvidia-387
   ```

   made my machine unable to get to the graphic mode (I had to `purge`; to be honest I may used another nvidia version than 387). I would write a comment advising to be careful, but I don't have enough reputation.

Could you help me with that problem?

**EDIT:**

I have added informations about CPU, frequency of crashes, short description of steps performed to solve the problem, improved formatting, removed mistakes.

**SECOND EDIT:**

I have reinstalled `Ubuntu` using USB stick. The problem still appears. I would like to add, that I have observed, that after restarting machine using power button, the system notifies me with **`System program problem detected`** `Do you want to report the problem now?`.

**THIRD EDIT:**

I have performed following steps related to graphic card drivers believing, that it could help overcome the problem, but the problem still exists. I have run below command, to check which driver is  recommended:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

and it showed me, that it is `nvidia-driver-440`.
Then, I have opened `Software & Updates` by running in terminal:

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

and clicked on `Additional Drivers` tab. Finally, I have chosen `Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-440 (open source)`, which made `Using X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)` the unchosen option, as shown below and clicked `Apply Changes`. 
[image: chosen graphic card driver]

I think, that after the change described above, I had ~ 1 day free of freezes. But finally - the problem still appears.